# Regular expression for Email with custom domain only

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I need regular expression for Email with custom domain only, means I want to exclude:

@live, @hotmail, @outlook, @aol, @yahoo, @rocketmail, @gmail, @gmx.com, @mail.com, @inbox.com, @icloud, @aim, @yandex, @zoho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two regex tests for your candidate strings in a single loop.

1. In the first test, you check for the unwanted domains and skip the string if you get a match:

   ```
   /^[\w-\._\+%]+@(live|hotmail|outlook|aol|yahoo|rocketmail|gmail|gmx\.com|mail.com|inbox.com|icloud|aim|yandex|zoho)\./
   ```
2. In the second test, you use your standard email regex.

Comment: this is the for email :^[\w-\._\+%]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6}$ where exactly should I replace

Comment: @Amir Updated the solution.  For the sake of simplicity, readability, and maintainability, use two regexes.  The first filters out the "bad" domains, then the second is your standard email regex.

Comment: my final use :
^[\w-\._\+%]+@(?!(live|hotmail|outlook|aol|yahoo|rocketmail|gmail|gmx\.com|mail\.com|inbox\.com|icloud|aim|yandex|zoho))(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6}$

Comment: @David, he can only provide a pattern, not code

Comment: That filters out `foo@cpan.org`

Answer (score 2):

Add the following immediately after the `@` in your email address pattern:

```
(?!(?:live|hotmail|outlook|aol|yahoo|rocketmail|gmail|
   gmx\.com|mail\.com|inbox\.com|icloud|aim|yandex|zoho)$)
```

Be sure to use a case-insensitive match.

(Line break added for readability.)

Comment: thanks but I need regular expression contains all this to use in server side and client side without java script thanks again

Comment: Oops, I thought this was tagged Perl. What coding language will you use on the client side, then?

Comment: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "*")

Comment: MVC razor convert this to jquery

Comment: the advantage from this MVC validation check server and client

Comment: this is the for email :^[\w-\._\+%]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6}$ where exactly should I replace

Comment: Updated my answer. Note that your pattern doesn't match a lot of valid email addresses :(

Comment: my final use : ^[\w-\._\+%]+@(?!(live|hotmail|outlook|aol|yahoo|rocketmail|gmail|gmx\.com|mail\‌​.com|inbox\.com|icloud|aim|yandex|zoho))(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6}$

Answer (score 0):

thanks @ikegami and @David my answer I combine between your answer and it's work, most part from David.
Regular expression:

```
^[\w-\._\+%]+@(?!(live|hotmail|outlook|aol|yahoo|rocketmail|gmail|gmx\.com|mail\.com|inbox\.com|icloud|aim|yandex|zoho)$)(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6}$
```

Comment: Removing the $ broke it. Your version excludes foo@hotmail.com and foo@livewire.com

Comment: ok @ikegami should I make my answer is the correct one ?

Comment: The `$` is still not there.

Comment: I edit in my code and forget to edit here

Comment: should I make my answer is the correct one ?

Comment: Anything but the one that's completely wrong! (David's) It doesn't even allow `foo@cpan.org` anymore.

Comment: For efficiency, you should have changed `(?:...)` to `(...)`. All that did is made it slower.

Comment: @ikegami I miss something we just specify known domains by .com
^[\w-\._\+%]+@(?!(live\.com|hotmail\.com|outlook\.com|aol\.com|yahoo\.com|rocketmail\.com|gmail\.com|gmx\.com|mail\.com|inbox\.com|icloud\.com|aim\.com|yandex\.com|zoho\.com))(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6}$
what do you say ?
one more thing I need regular expression work case insensitive?
sorry for disturb you

Comment: I don't understand the first question. // You need case insensitive matching because someone could use `foo@LIVE` instead of `foo@live` to get around your filter. (Domains names are case-insensitive.)

Comment: yes my expression work case sensitive so Live and liVe and livE allowed in this expression, question one that the known domains for email are only .com true?

Comment: False. Any domain can be used for email. I can be reached through a .org address and a .ca address. Google could create `elgoog@google` if they so desired.